# Restrict updating of Incident in TFS for 1 current user only

Tags: tfs-2015

In TFS, is there a way that we can restrict updating of 1 Incident ticket for just 1 current user only? Like perhaps adding a functionality that if 2 users are updating 1 same ticket at the same time will encounter an error message like "Ticket is being updated by another user. Try again later."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this.

It's pretty hard to get a collision these days in TFS 2017 as it is at the field level.